# Is it possible to have 2 tasks on the same date in angular-gantt?

Tags: html, angularjs, gantt-chart

I'm trying to make in a webapp a gantt-chart to display some data in a nicer way, using angular-gantt.
Some tasks are overlapping in certain rows, but the bars are displayed.

Is it possible to have the two thinner bars in the same row one under the other (not overlapping) ? or should i better create a separate row ?

ps. i'm not exactly a developer so maybe the explanation / question is not clear enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

You can do it by setting the property `daily = 'false'` in the place where you define your gantt chart (`<div gantt data=...>`).

```
div ng-app="appGanttChart" ng-controller="controllerGanttChart">
    <div gantt data="data"
         daily="false">
        <gantt-tree enabled="true"></gantt-tree>
        <gantt-groups enabled="true" 
        <gantt-tooltips enabled="true"></gantt-tooltips>
        <gantt-resize-sensor></gantt-resize-sensor>
    </div>
/div>
```

You don't need to set all the properties I have set, I was just giving an example.

Setting up `daily="false"` should solve your problem.